# Queries not printing in console after upgrading to java 1.8. Hibernate version is 5 and jboss is 7

Tags: java, logging

When debugging or executing the application queries are not getting printed in the console. I am using java 1.8, hibernate 5 and jboss7. For logging purpose log4j-1.2.17.jar is used. Is this problem due to any configuration or is it because of the log4j jar version issue?

Answer (score 0):

Please check the property in your hibernate config xml

```
<!--hibernate.cfg.xml -->
<property name="show_sql">true</property>
```

for additional thing you can set these properties

Format the generated SQL statement to make it more readable, but takes up more screen space -

```
<!--hibernate.cfg.xml -->
<property name="format_sql">true</property>
```

Hibernate will put comments inside all generated SQL statements to hint what’s the generated SQL trying to do -

```
<!--hibernate.cfg.xml -->
<property name="use_sql_comments">true</property>
```

From log4j side check this (for detailed logs - set it as DEBUG)

```
log4j.logger.org.hibernate=info
```

in XML version of log4j config file:

```
<logger name="org.hibernate">
  <level value="info"/> 
</logger>
```

Comment: and are you sure that hibernate properties are getting registered

Comment: Except the sql query other logs like exceptions, api calls are getting printed to the console.

Comment: check if log4j config is correct , added info above

Comment: it is not orinting normal sql queries also.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/190688/discussion-between-user3292629-and-ashish-shetkar).

Answer (score 0):

This is because hiberante has cached the results and not going to the database to fetch the records.

Try a different record and you should see the select statement on the console